# PHP convert Japanese to hex

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, hex

I have a string consisting of some latin words, special characters and Japanese characters. The string is UTF-8 encoded. I would like to convert everything to hex.

I have tried serveral approaches but somehow the Japanese characters are not converted correctly. Everything else is transformed correctly.

As an example, I want to convert the Japanese characters for "test" which look like this: テスト

When I try this function:

```
     function utf8StringToHexString($string) {
       $nums = array();
       $convmap = array(0x0, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff);
       $strlen = mb_strlen($string, "UTF-8");
       for ($i = 0; $i < $strlen; $i++) {
       $ch = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, "UTF-8");
       $decimal = substr(mb_encode_numericentity($ch, $convmap, "UTF-8"), -5, 4);
       $nums[] = "" .base_convert($decimal, 10, 16). ";";
       }
       return implode("", $nums);
   }
```

I get "9b6;9a9;9b8".

When I try:

```
function strToHex($string)
          {
              $hex='';
              for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
              {
                  $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
              }
              return $hex;
          }
```

I get "e38386e382b9e38388", which on a conversion page I found was labeled "hexadecimal utf-8".

What I would like to have is "30 C6 30 B9 30 C8" which on the same conversion page is labeled "hexadecimal raw". When I run the utf8StringToHexString function on the latin text I get the "hexadecimal raw" output.

when I run mb_detect_encoding(), it outputs "UTF-8" for both the latin and the Japanese characters.

thank you for your help!

Comment: it's correct if you print the result from your loop `decimal`--> `hexadecimal` second function give correct result  `227 ---> e3
131 ---> 83
134 ---> 86
227 ---> e3
130 ---> 82
185 ---> b9
227 ---> e3
131 ---> 83
136 ---> 88`.

Comment: the above result from this code inside the loop `echo  ord($string[$i]) . ' ---> ' . dechex(ord($string[$i])) . '<br>';`

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly. This function gives me the result "e38386e382b9e38388". But what I want to have instead is "30 C6 30 B9 30 C8".

Comment: when i test the second function with `テスト` i get this sequence of decimal number `227
131
134
227
130
185
227
131
136` for example  hexa of `227` is `E3` not `30` what you expect.

Comment: thank you, you are right, e38386e382b9e38388 is actually the correct hex string

Comment: You are welcome if you want correct Formatted hexadecimal  codes try the helper function i posted instead of `dechex`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This refactoring of your second function :

```
 /**
 * @param $string
 * @return string
 */
function strToHex($string){
    $hex = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $hex .= dec2hex(ord($string[$i])) . ' ';
    }
    return $hex;
}

/**
 * @param $number
 * @return string
 */
function dec2hex($number){
    $hexvalues = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F');
    $hexval = '';
    while ($number != '0') {
        $hexval = $hexvalues[bcmod($number, '16')] . $hexval;
        $number = bcdiv($number, '16', 0);
    }
    return $hexval;
}
```